# List VuePress articles on another website using NodeJs and Gulp

Tags: vuepress

I'm using VuePress for my blog on url like https://mywebsite.fr/blog and I have my real website on https://mywebsite.fr that run on NodeJS with Gulp

My question is: there is a way to list all my blog articles on my website (something like a category "Live from our blog" and display with custom css the latest 3 articles from VuePress blog)

Maybe using a NodeJS plugin or with PHP script ?

Hope someone will have a solution for this !

Thanks and kind regards,
Florian.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the plugin `vuepress-plugin-feed` for generate a JSON List with all posts.

And in your website you must load this list for show main posts.

Important link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuepress-plugin-feed

Are you looking for this?

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)